# why state is not updating in this component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On the basis of selectedQuestion I am displaying the question component but when remove function is run after clicking close button of last question then state is not being updated and hence it points to old index and question disappears.

I am using ref to update the currentIndex of the question its working but if i use state then its not.

I think its happening due to state not being updated in the same render cycle.

I have tried:

1. passing of setState to the removeFunction and updating there
2. i have also used the updater function format of setState.

```
<span className={styles.questionRemoveIcon}
                onClick={() => {
                  if (index > 0) {
                    // setSelectedQuestion(index - 1);
                    // console.log("----------");
                    // debugger;

                    setSelectedQuestion((prev) => {
                      debugger;
                      selectedQuestionRef.current = prev - 1;
                      removeQuestion(index);
                      return prev - 1;
                    });

                    debugger;
                    console.log(questions, index, selectedQuestion);
                  }
                }}
              >
                x
              </span>
```

```
     {questions?.map((q, index) => {
          debugger;

          return (
            <>
//Here if instead of selectedQuestionRef.current if i use state variable selectedQuestion then its doesnt show any question.
              {index === selectedQuestionRef.current && (
                <Question
                  key={q.id}
                  index={q.id}
                  question={q.question}
                  options={q.options}
                  timerType={q.timerType}
                  optionTypes={q.optionTypes}
                  selectedOptionType={q.optionsType}
                />
              )}
            </>
          );
        })}
```

Complete component:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { MCQContext } from "../../../context/McqContext";

import styles from "./CreateMcq.module.css";
import Question from "./Question";
import { setSelectionRange } from "@testing-library/user-event/dist/utils";

const CreateMcq = () => {
  const { questions, addQuestion, removeQuestion, updateTimerType } =
    useContext(MCQContext);
  const [selectedQuestion, setSelectedQuestion] = useState(0);
  const selectedQuestionRef = useRef(0);

  const handleAddQuestion = () => {
    addQuestion({
      id: questions.length,
      question: "",
      optionTypes: [
        {
          name: "Text",
          value: "Text",
        },
        { name: "Image URL", value: "Image URL" },
        { name: "Text and Image URL", value: "Text and Image URL" },
      ],
      optionsType: "Text",
      options: Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, index) => ({
        content: "",
        imageContent: "",
      })),
      timerType: "OFF",
      correctOption: 0,
    });
    selectedQuestionRef.current = questions.length;
    setSelectedQuestion(questions.length);
  };

  const handleTimerTypeChange = (e) => {
    const newTimerType = e.target.value;
    updateTimerType(selectedQuestionRef.current, newTimerType);
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setSelectedQuestion((prevSelected) =>
  //     prevSelected >= questions.length ? questions.length - 1 : prevSelected
  //   );
  // }, [questions.length]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.questionBox}>
        <div className={styles.questionHeader}>
          <div className={styles.addQuestionBar}>
            {questions.map((q, index) => (
              <div
                className={`${styles.questionCircle} ${
                  index === selectedQuestionRef.current
                    ? styles.questionCircleActive
                    : ""
                }`}
                onClick={() => {
                  selectedQuestionRef.current = index;
                  setSelectedQuestion(index);
                }}
              >
                <p>{index + 1}</p>
                {index === questions?.length - 1 && index > 0 && (
                  <span
                    className={styles.questionRemoveIcon}
                    onClick={() => {
                      if (index > 0) {
                        // setSelectedQuestion(index - 1);
                        // console.log("----------");
                        // debugger;

                        setSelectedQuestion((prev) => {
                          debugger;
                          selectedQuestionRef.current = prev - 1;
                          removeQuestion(index);
                          return prev - 1;
                        });

                        debugger;
                        console.log(questions, index, selectedQuestion);
                      }
                    }}
                  >
                    x
                  </span>
                )}
              </div>
            ))}
            {questions.length < 5 && (
              <div
                className={styles.addQuestionCircle}
                onClick={handleAddQuestion}
              >
                +
              </div>
            )}
          </div>

          <div className="totalQuestions">Max 5 Questions.</div>
        </div>
        {questions?.map((q, index) => {
          debugger;

          return (
            <>
              {index === selectedQuestionRef.current && (
                <Question
                  key={q.id}
                  index={q.id}
                  question={q.question}
                  options={q.options}
                  timerType={q.timerType}
                  optionTypes={q.optionTypes}
                  selectedOptionType={q.optionsType}
                />
              )}
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className={styles.timerType}>
        <div style={{ marginRight: "auto" }}>Timer Type:</div>
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="timerType"
            value="5 Sec"
            onChange={handleTimerTypeChange}
            checked={
              questions[selectedQuestionRef.current]?.timerType === "5 Sec"
            }
          />{" "}
          5 Sec
        </label>
        <label style={{ marginLeft: "0.5rem" }}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="timerType"
            value="10 Sec"
            onChange={handleTimerTypeChange}
            checked={
              questions[selectedQuestionRef.current]?.timerType === "10 Sec"
            }
          />
          10 Sec
        </label>
        <label style={{ marginLeft: "0.5rem" }}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="timerType"
            value="OFF"
            onChange={handleTimerTypeChange}
            checked={
              questions[selectedQuestionRef.current]?.timerType === "OFF"
            }
          />{" "}
          OFF
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.btnContainer}>
        <button className={styles.cancelBtn}>Cancel</button>
        <button className={styles.createBtn}>Create Quiz</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateMcq;
```

MCQcontext:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useCallback } from "react";

export const MCQContext = createContext();

export const MCQProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      question: "",
      optionTypes: [
        {
          name: "Text",
          value: "Text",
        },
        { name: "Image URL", value: "Image URL" },
        { name: "Text and Image URL", value: "Text and Image URL" },
      ],
      optionsType: "Text",
      options: Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, index) => ({
        content: "",
        imageContent: "",
      })),
      timerType: "OFF",
      correctOption: 0,
    },
  ]);
  const [nextId, setNextId] = useState(1);

  const addQuestion = useCallback(
    (newQuestion) => {
      const questionWithId = { ...newQuestion, id: nextId };
      setQuestions((prevQuestions) => [...prevQuestions, questionWithId]);
      setNextId((prevId) => prevId + 1);
    },
    [nextId]
  );

  const removeQuestion = useCallback((index) => {
    setQuestions((prevQuestions) => {
      debugger;
      const newQuestions = [...prevQuestions];
      newQuestions.splice(index, 1);
      return newQuestions;
    });
  }, []);

  const updateQuestionText = useCallback((qid, newText) => {
    setQuestions((prevQuestions) => {
      debugger;
      const questionIndex = prevQuestions.findIndex(
        (question) => question.id === qid
      );
      const updatedQuestions = [...prevQuestions];
      updatedQuestions[questionIndex].question = newText;
      return updatedQuestions;
    });
  }, []);

  const updateOptionType = useCallback((questionId, newType) => {
    setQuestions((prevQuestions) => {
      const questionIndex = prevQuestions.findIndex(
        (question) => question.id === questionId
      );
      if (questionIndex !== -1) {
        const updatedQuestions = [...prevQuestions];
        updatedQuestions[questionIndex].optionsType = newType;
        return updatedQuestions;
      } else {
        return prevQuestions;
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const updateCorrectOption = useCallback((questionIndex, newCorrectOption) => {
    setQuestions((prevQuestions) => {
      const updatedQuestions = [...prevQuestions];
      updatedQuestions[questionIndex].correctOption = +newCorrectOption;
      return updatedQuestions;
    });
  }, []);

  const updateTimerType = useCallback((questionIndex, newTimerType) => {
    setQuestions((prevQuestions) => {
      const updatedQuestions = [...prevQuestions];
      updatedQuestions[questionIndex].timerType = newTimerType;
      return updatedQuestions;
    });
  }, []);

  const updateOptionContent = useCallback(
    (questionIndex, optionIndex, newContent) => {
      setQuestions((prevQuestions) => {
        const updatedQuestions = [...prevQuestions];
        updatedQuestions[questionIndex].options[optionIndex].content =
          newContent;
        return updatedQuestions;
      });
    },
    []
  );

  const updateImageContent = useCallback(
    (questionIndex, optionIndex, newImageContent) => {
      setQuestions((prevQuestions) => {
        const updatedQuestions = [...prevQuestions];
        updatedQuestions[questionIndex].options[optionIndex].imageContent =
          newImageContent;
        return updatedQuestions;
      });
    },
    []
  );

  const initialEmptyQuestion = {
    id: 0,
    question: "",
    options: Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, index) => ({
      type: "text",
      content: "",
      selected: index === 0,
    })),
    timerType: "off",
    correctOption: "",
  };

  const contextValue = {
    questions: questions.length === 0 ? [initialEmptyQuestion] : questions,
    addQuestion,
    removeQuestion,
    updateQuestionText,
    updateOptionType,
    updateCorrectOption,
    updateTimerType,
    updateOptionContent,
    updateImageContent,
  };

  return (
    <MCQContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</MCQContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Mind that `ref.current` is not reactive, means changing its value won't re-render your component.
(see: https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#caveats)

I suggest using a index state for selecting the right question to display, similar to carousel functionality, like that:

```
const [currentQuestionId, setCurrentQuestionId] = useState(0);
const handleNextQuestion = (direction) => {
  // Don't forget to protect the end/start of the array so it won't return undefined objects
  if (direction === 'next') {
    setCurrentQuestionId(currentQuestionId + 1)
  } else {
    setCurrentQuestionId(currentQuestionId - 1)
  }  
}
```